# How can I get 'more posts' or 'other posts' using Facebook C# GRAPH API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a question.

I think that Facebook C# GRAPH API only supports method that get most recently posts or messages.

example)

```
JSONObject me = fbAPI.Get("/me/feed?access_token=" + this.app_access_token);
```

Is there any additional parameter to get the previous posts or messages?

If it's not possible, Is Other API ( PHP, Javascript ... ) supporting this?

-jack-

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with the C# SDK, but if it follows the convention of other Graph API compatible SDKs you should be able to do this:

```
JSONObject me = fbAPI.Get("/me/feed?limit=25&since=1311007970&access_token=" + this.app_access_token)
```

The `limit` parameter will restrict the number of posts that are retrieved at once and the `since` parameter is a Unix timestamp that will allow you to query for posts further back in time. Check out the Paging section on this page for more information:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#reading